# How to take a Sql column value and translate the html into a asp label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, infopath

Sql column value (generated from a InfoPath RTF control):

```
<strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><font color="#7030a0">This</font></strong> is a <font xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" color="#ff0000"><strong>richtextfield</strong></font>
```

I have a label in asp.net:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOne" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

How can I translate the column value to display the output in the asp label.

Example:

```
The asp label above would display: `this (in bold and in color) is a richtextfield(in bold and in color)`
```

Comment: Have you tried `lblOne.Text = yourSqlValue`? What's your code behind?

Comment: Holding html in values, and then dropping that directly onto a page, is somewhat... risky, from a XSS aspect (unless you know that html is pre-validated and known safe). To do what you want, you'd need to inject **unescaped** values onto a page, which is usually not what is intended... also: the `xmlns` is overkill, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell is being to polite.  **Don't do this you will be hacked**. This is why markdown (like on stackoverflow) exists.  *nuff said*

Comment: @Hogan in the case of XSS, it is more a case of "do this any your users' accounts will be hacked" - although if one of those users is one of your devs / admins, it may amount to the same thing...

Comment: @MarcGravell - I believe that devs / admins are common enough it is the same thing, but I guess the distinction can be useful if access is limited.  Seems better to me to not include the XSS vulnerability in the first place, but ya know, I'm old fashioned.

Comment: @Hogan totally with you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better served with a `Literal` value since you're using raw HTML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
```

In the code-behind

```
Literal1.Text = yourSQLValue;
```

You should consider not placing HTML directly into your page however.

Comment: To stress what others have mentioned, storing HTML in to a database and placing it directly into a page is VERY risky unless you can guarantee it has been sanitized in some fashion.